# Using PEAR package Horde_Text_Diff

Tags: php, dependencies, pear

I installed [Horde_Text_Diff](http://www.horde.org/libraries/Horde_Text_Diff/library), which supersedes [Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/). Here's the problem: when I try to use it, it gives me:

```
Class 'Horde_Text_Diff_Engine_Native' not found
```

I looked at the files, and it looks like there are fifteen  or so classes that depend on each other, and none of the files include each other. Do I have to do this manually? Again, there are about fifteen files.

Is this how PEAR packages are supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a PSR-0 compatible autoloader that automatically includes classes when they are available from your include path. Horde provides one, [Horde_Autoloader](http://www.horde.org/libraries/Horde_Autoloader/).