# Horde_text_diff issue on debian server

Tags: php, pear

I have a server running Debian. I have subfolders: each of them is a new virtual host for each website.

I installed pear from the apt get command (pear and php pear), without any problem. I then installed Horde_diff_text package as well.

I'm now trying to run the example. I copied and past the 'Text' folder (which contains the files for the command) in my virtual host.

But the file example is not working, as well as other scripts (Horde_Text_Diff string comparison library only comparing 1st character of strings)

I followed the instructions to check out my installation, everything is fine (http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php)

I added at the beginning of the script this line:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . ":/usr/share/pear");
```

even though i'm not exactly sure what path i should include (when i get include path i have this :

.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear

So I don't really know what to do anymore to get text_diff work. Is there an issue because my pear and text_diff files are not on my virtual host folder ? What could be wrong ?

Comment: (Repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482185/horde-text-diff-pear-trouble). That's still a little vague (and long-winded) on where you actually copied files to. Or what the code or error message is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Basically, i used the apt get method to install pear and text_diff. i checked if everything was well following pear instructions. Text_diff doesn't work. So my question now is: what should i do to make it work ? I assume using the function right into my script should work, but it's not. I also have an issue about the script files to include (diff.php, renderer.php...) they are not located in my virtual host, should i add them ?

Comment: Hi, so the error message is "Fatal error: Class 'Horde_Text_Diff_Engine_Native not found in home/mywebsite/test/Text/Diff.php.  I installed an autoloader like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313255/using-pear-package-horde-text-diff  but still doesn't work...:(